# High Availability in SharePoint 2013 Central admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration

I have **2 apps servers** and **2 WFE servers**, I would like to have **high availability configuration** for SharePoint central admin. So that if one apps server goes down, another apps server will be active. I need to know steps to configure this topology. Do I need to host CA in both the apps server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow these steps.

- configure the central admin on both app server
- edit the AAM settings
- make a registry change
- now setup dns record
- configure the load balancer

Read complete blog here, this is valid for 2013.
http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx

Comment: What i have do if i need to host my Web application in WFE IIS only,Because       i want to have my apps server IIS to host only central admin site...

Comment: When you configure the central admin select the app server for hosting as mentioned in the blog. Web application on wfe is business as usual

Comment: You should always host Web Applications on all servers. SharePoint 2010/2013's topology service isn't smart and will route requests that cannot be served to servers that do not run the Foundation Web service.

Comment: Need some clear picture on hosting "Web Application" in WFE IIS only...